# Converting empty string to integer

Tags: coldfusion, integer, string

Currently, my application is showing this error message:

"The value '' cannot be converted to a number."

Which doesn't surprise me. The variable was just added, so the variable is an empty string for anyone who used the application before I made the new field.

```
<td><cfif studentRecruitComments neq "">
        <a href="javascript: showContent('#studentRecruitComments#')">
            #studentRecruit#
        </a>
     <cfelse>
         #studentRecruit#
     </cfif>
</td>
<cfset tstudentRecruit = tstudentRecruit + studentRecruit>
```

The math at the end is for a tallying system. The variable `tstudentRecruit` is set to 0 before this line too, so it definitely lies in the studentRecruit variable. What is the proper way of converting the empty string to an integer? Is there anything that is blatantly wrong here?

Comment: Uh, `<cfif studentRecruit EQ '' ><cfset studentRecruit = 0 /></cfif>` ?

Comment: Alternatively, look at functions [**isNumeric**](http://cfdocs.org/isNumeric) and/or [**val**](http://cfdocs.org/val) to do this.

Comment: The fact that you are tallying anything at all might be a blatant error.  One of the principles of a normalized database design is to not store calculated values.  Of course I have no idea what you plan to do with the variable once you get it working.

Comment: Maybe cfparam is what you are looking for?  <cfparam name="studentRecruit" default="0" />

Comment: *before I made the new field* As an aside, if you mean added new database column, most databases allow you assign a default value to existing rows when adding a new column. (The exact sql syntax is db dependent). So you could simply populate that column with a default value like `0`, rather than letting it be `null`. (Whether that is the right approach depends on your app. Just throwing it out there as an option).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply make use of the val() function which either returns the number or if conversion fails, returns zero. So you don't have to check if your variable is numeric or not.

```
<cfset tstudentRecruit = tstudentRecruit + val(studentRecruit)>
```

Comment: How about: `<cfset tstudentRecruit += val(studentRecruit)>`

Comment: You have to be careful recommending syntax like += as it is relatively new and the CF version isn't indicated anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I'd change the code slightly to read:

```
<td>
    <cfif NOT Len(trim(studentRecruitComments))>
        <a href="javascript: showContent('#studentRecruitComments#')">
            #studentRecruit#
        </a>
     <cfelse>
         #studentRecruit#
     </cfif>
</td>
<cfif NOT isNumeric(studentRecruit)>
    <cfset studentRecruit = 0>
</cfif>
<cfset tstudentRecruit = tstudentRecruit + studentRecruit>
```

Few things I'm doing here:

First, changing **cfif studentRecruitComments neq ""** to actually check on the length of the string as oposed to checking if it's empty. I;m adding trim to remove any empty spaces that might exist.

I then check that the variable **studentRecruit** is a number, and if it isn't, I then set it to 0, that way, your code won't fail.

Obviously I don't really know the context of your code, as I think it could be further improved.

However, using my code snippet will cause the error to disappear.

HTH

Comment: why not just say `<cfif isNumeric(studentRecruit)>Add the value</cfif>` ? If the value is 0 no need to add it to the existing counter

Comment: I went with setting studentRecruit as he may need the variable along the way on his script

Comment: Yep, we definitely need more context. The above is a good explanation, but would not work if this code is within a query loop and `studentRecruit` is a query column. Within a query loop the unscoped `<cfset studentRecruit = 0>` does **not** overwrite the query column value. It creates a separate variable in the `variables` scope. But the addition operation would still use the query value (because `studentRecruit` is unscoped). So ultimately you would still get the same error. As @Marcos said we need more context to provide the correct answer for your specific code.